# ValueError: Passed Tensor should have graph attribute that is equal to current graph

Tags: tensorflow, iterator

This may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799041/valueerror-passed-tensor-should-have-graph-attribute-that-is-equal-to-curr). The symptom is the same, but the root cause may be different.

```
self.estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[16,32,16,8],
    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
)

...

def train_input_fn(self):
  self.train_features, self.train_labels = self.train_iter.get_next()
  return self.train_features, self.train_labels

...

def perform_training(self):
  self.batch_size = 32
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(self.train_features), self.train_labels))
  self.train_dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(self.batch_size)
  self.train_iter = self.train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  print("train_iter: {}".format(self.train_iter))
  self.estimator.train( self.train_input_fn, steps=self.num_epochs )
```

The error happens at the self.estimator.train call:

```
ValueError: Passed Tensor("dnn/head/weighted_loss/value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) should have graph attribute that is equal to current graph <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7feb79598b38>.
```

The structure of `self.train_features` is consistent with `feature_columns`. Could you tell what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: How is your self.train_input_fn defined? From a very broad overview with respect to the answer you have referenced, this function should return the dataset iterator that you have defined above. That way, it will be a part of the same graph, as the estimator builds the graph given an input function.

Comment: @kvish, added `train_input_fn` definition to the question, thanks.

Comment: the problem is with your iterator being defined inside the perform_training function. When you call the Estimator train, everything inside the input_fn is built in to a new graph. But here, your iterator is already defined outside in another graph. Shift everything from the self.batch_size to self.train_iter in to train_input_fn and it should be fine!